# How to configure reverse proxy via Zuul2?

Tags: java, web, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, netflix-zuul

Could you tell how to configure Zuul2 as reverse proxy without Eureka?
For example, if I want all requests which sending to http://localhost will be routes to https://some-app.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com ?
For example if I open http://localhost/index.html I need to be proxied to https://some-app.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/index.html

I have tried different configurations but got 301 Moved permanently instead proxy pass to target url.

For example this configuration at application.properties doesn't work (I got 301 answer when try to open http://localhost/index.html):

```
zuul.server.port.main=80

# Loading Filters Paths
zuul.filters.root=com.example.cs.sample.filters
zuul.filters.packages=${zuul.filters.root}.endpoint,${zuul.filters.root}.inbound,${zuul.filters.root}.outbound

# Deactivate Eureka
eureka.shouldFetchRegistry=false
eureka.validateInstanceId=false

# Load balancing

api.ribbon.listOfServers=some-app.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com:80
api.ribbon.client.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
```

Comment: I guess that Zuul2 performs 2 requests to gateway from api.ribbon.listOfServers.
On first request Zuul2 got in code behind 200, and on second it got 304 Not Modified. 304 response breaks Zuul2 logics.

If I configure Spring Cloud Gateway in the same way (without Zuul1 and of course Zuul2, - pure SCG), then it works correctly.

Is it bug of Zuul2??? Or it needs some configuration? Any ideas?